# How can i perform a PFRelation query using parse in ios

Tags: ios, parse-platform, relational-database

I have created a relation between two tables

LocationClass Table In this table i have a column with location images with the relation of another table ie., Assets

![This is location Class Image, If user selected a locationName, need to get the locationImages(viewRelation)][1]

Assets Table, It contains Images for each relation Now my query is how to get the data from relation database. Here if user select a location means i need to get a group of images for the relevant location ![This is my Assets Table, here need to retrieve the images based on the selected location from the locationClass Table][2]

Till now, I have done with this format

```
PFQuery *queryObj = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"LocationClass"];
sharedDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

// Run the query
[queryObj whereKey:@"locationImages" equalTo:[PFObject objectWithoutDataWithClassName:@"Assets" objectId:@"aAPzhdO4w6"]];

[queryObj findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error)
    {
        [locationArray addObjectsFromArray:objects];
        sharedDelegate.locationsArray = locationArray;
        [locationDropDown reloadData];
    }
}];
```

In my location array for a single object contain

```
<__NSArrayM 0xaee4eb0>(
<LocationClass:ZtOP9voUak:(null)> {
    LocationId = WilliamsBurgId;
    LocationName = WilliamsBurg;
    locationImages = "<PFRelation: 0xaf53c30>(<00000000>.(null) -> Assets)";
}
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution for to pass the data from PFRelation Object

```
    // should pass the main table name

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"LocationClass"];
    // should pass object id for the selected row
    PFObject *getImageObject = [query getObjectWithId:@"need to pass object id from the maintable"];


    locationImagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    // To acess the data from the relation object

    PFRelation *relationObj = [getImageObject relationForKey:@"locationImages"];
    PFQuery *query1 = [relationObj query];
    [query1 findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {

        [locationImagesArray addObjectsFromArray:results];
        for (int imgCount = 0; imgCount < [locationImagesArray count]; imgCount ++) {

            PFFile *getImage1 = [[locationImagesArray valueForKey:@"Image"] objectAtIndex:imgCount];
            [getImage1 getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *imageData, NSError *error)
             {

                 if (imageData!=nil) {
                     UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
                     activityImage.image = image;

                     NSLog(@"location image output");

                     NSLog(@"location image output : %@", activityImage.image);

                 }
             }];

        }
```